# Failed to connect to localhost 127.0.0.1:44373

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, https, webapi

I'm using xamarin forms + asp.net core web api. If I try to call from Postmat then everything is fine, but if I call from a device (I use a real device, not an emulator) then I have this error "Failed to connect to localhost / 127.0.0.1: 44373"
My string "https: // localhost: 44373 / api / v1 / reports / get_reports" Phone local IP - 192.168.0.101

My ipconfig
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4dbf:c945:4125:74c8%5
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.102
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Comment: do not use localhost, use the real IP or FQDN of the server.  Localhost is the address a machine uses to connect TO ITSELF

Comment: now i have this - failed to connect to /000.00.000.000 (port 44373) from /192.168.0.101 (port 48471

Comment: if you are using the VS web server, it is not configured to allow remote connections by default.

Comment: Tack a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device